# Azure Storage Emulator has stopped working

Tags: azure

When I try to debug the Windows Azure application using VS 2010, the following error dialog, titled `Windows Azure Storage Emulator` appears:

`The 'system.serviceModel/services' configuration section cannot be created. The machine.config file is missing information. Verify that this configuration section is properly registered and that you have correctly spelled the section name. For Windows Communication Foundation sections, run ServiceModelReg.exe -i to fix this error.`

Immediatelly I get notification that storage emulator has stopped working.

Attaching a debugger shows the following information:

`An unhandled exception ('System.Configuration.ConfigurationerrorsException') occured in DSService.exe [7000].`

I run Visual Studio as administrator. Tried doing the `DSInit` before and the database was successfully created but that did not solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Edit: the SQLEXPRESS is running and I disabled the SQLSERVER instance to leave only the SQLEXPRESS but the problem is the same. Maybe there is some kind of configuration somewhere to tell the Azure emulator which server to use?

This problem looks very similar to [How to fix error running storage emulator for Azure in VS 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083505/how-to-fix-error-running-storage-emulator-for-azure-in-vs-2010). I had same errors when I used incorrect server name in `DSIinit` but it does not apply in my case.

Comment: Conclusion so far was that something was wrong with my OS since reinstalls of various components (IIS, SQL, .NET) did not help. Decided to do the development on virtual machine instead - works great.

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out the silly stuff, is the cloud service project set as the startup project and is the Storage Emulator manually running (you can see it in the task tray).

I've seen similar instances of this type of situation where you don't launch the cloud project but you do launch the web site. This doesn't cause the storage emulator to be started (if it isn't already) and can result in a similar error message.

You can also test the azure storage emulator outside of your solution by simply launching it manually. Just go into start menu and type "storage emulator" and launch it. You'll be prompted for admin permissions a couple times then it should launch ok. If it does fail to launch, then you have a configuration issue and DSInit may help, or perhaps even re-installing the SDK.

Comment: The project is set as the startup. And when I try to launch the storage emulator alone it crashes in the same way. Reinstalling SDK and even .NET framework did not help also. Currently trying to remove SQL servers and install the SQL Server Express alone. I do not see how configuration could be an issue being the default. I am currently willing to blame the SQL Server the most.

Comment: SO you had SQL Server and SQL Express installed? Do you have full admin rights to both? WHat is the server name for SQL Express?

Comment: SQL Server's name is <machine_name> and SQL Server Express name is <machine_name>\SQLEXPRESS. By the way, I have just tested this out on my other machine (it has ONLY SQL Server Express) - did a clean install of Azure, started the emulator and it worked just fine. Do you think SQL Server could make the problems?

Comment: The stock answer is that "it shouldn't" but it has in the past. An additional item to check is to see if the base database for the storage emulator exists in either your SQL Server or SQL Express databases. Then I seem to recall that there is a location to check to see which database your emulator is pointed at but can't recall where its at and unfortunately don't have time to search for it this morning. :(

Comment: By default, the base database does not get created at all since the emulator crashes before creating the database. However, it does get created when I call DSInit.exe explicitly with the SQL server's name provided. And it creates the database in either the Express and full versions of the SQL Server. After that, when I try to open the emulator, it crashes anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in jumping back on this Paul. Been busy. Anyways, I suspect you have messed up registry entry somewhere. But I'm not sure where it could be. I'll try to check and let you know.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I am still going to come back to this issue when I have more time for that. Currently virtual machine is sufficient but it is definitely not a good solution to the problem.

Comment: I have a similar/same problem. Both SQL Server and Express are installed, but I only use SQL Server. Used DsInit to initialize the db. When launching via VS (running as admininstrator), it launches computer emulator but not storage emulator. When I click on the emulator icon and try start storage emulator that way, it works, and I can then re-launch via VS and it connects succesfully.